VSCode with Ctags Support extension tags for System Verilog
I have installed Ctags on my Win11, the Ctags Support ext in my VSC is also installs.
When I run the recommended command:
    ;; ctags  -R -f .tags

I don't see any tags being collected.
I added the --verbose=yes option and saw that
The file is being skipped:
"ignoring .\testbench\tb.sv (unknown language)"
I added  a config file with this:
ctags.cnf
    --langdef=SystemVerilog
    --langmap=SystemVerilog:.sv

this time
OPENING .\testbench\tb.sv as SystemVerilog language file
But there is still nothing inside the .tags file under the header.
What else do I need to do to make it work with System Verilog?

you might be missing the specific language parser for SystemVerilog in Ctags.
try the following steps:
Download the SystemVerilog parser script for Ctags from the following link: https://github.com/rizkiarm/ctags-systemverilog/blob/master/systemverilog.ctags
Save the file as systemverilog.ctags in the share/ctags/ directory of your Ctags installation. The default location for this directory on Windows is C:\Program Files (x86)\CTags\share\ctags.
Create a new ctags.cnf file in your home directory (C:\Users\YourUsername\ on Windows) with the following content:
--langdef=SystemVerilog
--langmap=SystemVerilog:.sv
--regex-SystemVerilog=/module\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*(\(.*\))?\s*;/module \1 \2 \3/
--regex-SystemVerilog=/interface\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*(\(.*\))?\s*;/interface \1 \2 \3/
--regex-SystemVerilog=/program\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*(\(.*\))?\s*;/program \1 \2 \3/
--regex-SystemVerilog=/function\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*\((.*),?\s*(.*),?\s*\)/function \1 \2 (\3) (\4)/
--regex-SystemVerilog=/task\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*\((.*),?\s*(.*),?\s*\)/task \1 \2 (\3) (\4)/
--regex-SystemVerilog=/input\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+(\w+);/input \1 \2/
--regex-SystemVerilog=/output\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+(\w+);/output \1 \2/
--regex-SystemVerilog=/inout\s\+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+(\w+);/inout \1 \2/

This configuration file maps the relevant SystemVerilog constructs to Ctags.
Now, you can run the following command in the terminal:
ctags -R --verbose --options=ctags.cnf -f .tags .

This command should generate the .tags file with the correct tags for your SystemVerilog files.
If you still encounter issues, please ensure that the systemverilog.ctags file is in the correct location and that the ctags.cnf file is being used by Ctags. You can check the --verbose output to confirm that Ctags is parsing the SystemVerilog files correctly.

Thank you, I tried your code, but still no tags were collected.
I am using Exuberant ctags, should I switch to the newer Universal ctags?

You can download this extension to do the same thing.
Systemverilog extension
